# Replacing '\\' or '\\\\' in spark dataframe via sparklyr fails

Tags: r, apache-spark, backslash, sparklyr

I try to replace backslashes in spark dataframe. I wrote a functuion that works well with the R dataframe. I insert it into `spark_apply` and it does not work:

```
rm(back_slash_replace_func)

back_slash_replace_func <- function(x)
{

     cbind.data.frame(
          lapply(
          x, function(x) { if(class(x) == 'character'){ gsub(pattern = "\\", replacement = "/", x = x, fixed = T)} else { x } }
            )
     , stringsAsFactors = F
     )

}

## do in R

x <- data.frame(x = rep('\\', 10), stringsAsFactors = F)

back_slash_replace_func(x)

## do in spark

r_spark_connection <- spark_connect(master = "local")

xsp <- copy_to(r_spark_connection, x, overwrite = T)

start <- Sys.time()

spark_apply(
               x = xsp
               , f = back_slash_replace_func
               , memory = F
               )

Sys.time() - start
```

**It does not do the job, no error, no warning. What could be the case?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you should note, is that `copy_to` malformed your data. While `x` is:

```
x %>% head(1)
#    x
# 1 \\
```

`xsp` is

```
xsp %>% head(1)
# # Source:   lazy query [?? x 1]
# # Database: spark_connection
#   x    
#   <chr>
# 1 "\""
```

This is because spakrlyr dumps data to flat file, when you use `copy_to`. As a result it wouldn't work even locally:

```
xsp %>% collect %>% back_slash_replace_func %>% head(1)
#   x
# 1 "
```

If you'd create data frame directly:

```
df <-spark_session(r_spark_connection) %>%
  invoke("sql", "SELECT '\\\\' AS x FROM range(10)") %>% 
  sdf_register() 

df %>% collect %>% back_slash_replace_func %>% head(1)
#   x
# 1 /
```

this particular problem wouldn't appear.

The another problem here, is that `spark_apply` actually converts `strings` to `factors` (according to the [Kevin's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2835778/kevinykuo) comment this is tracked by [sparklyr:1295](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/issues/1295)) So instead of:

```
function(x) {
  if (is.character(x)) {
    gsub(pattern = "\\", replacement = "/", x = x, fixed = T)
  } else { x }
}
```

you'd rather need:

```
function(x) {
  if (is.factor(x)) {
    gsub(pattern = "\\", replacement = "/", x = as.character(x), fixed = T)
  } else { x }
}
```

But in practice just `translate`:

```
df %>% mutate(x = translate(x, "\\\\", "/")) %>% head(1)
# # Source:   lazy query [?? x 1]
# # Database: spark_connection
#   x    
#   <chr>
# 1 /
```